# gnome-shell weather

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I try install weather in gnome-shell via tutorials:

google.com/search?q=gnome+shell+weather

webupd8.org/2012/03/official-gnome-shell-extensions-weather.html

webupd8.org/2012/06/alternative-gnome-shell-weather.html

and still don't work, everything install without errors

gnome-tweak-tool from sudo and without looks same:

[image: oh no]

I just wanna have weather in panel :(

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ls -1
gnome-shell-extensions-ppa-precise.list
webupd8team-gnome3-precise.list
```

Comment: did you have any success with my solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are **two solutions** without having to add new ppa sources:

**1. gnome-shell-extensions-weather**

Do the following to have the weather in the **top panel** using `gnome-shell-extensions-weather`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-weather
```

Logout and back in.
Open the gnome-tweak-tool (`gnome-tweak-tool` in a terminal):
go to `Shell Extensions` and enable the weather indicator extension. It should appear in the top panel next to the time. Click on it for further configuration.

**2. indicator-weather**

This one will sit in the **bottom panel**.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-weather
```

There will also be an entry in the startup applications' list. If you want to see it  after the installation, run it from a terminal:

```
indicator-weather&
```

You can now go ahead and customize (adding locations, etc).